# Combining Promise.map with Promise.join

Tags: javascript, concurrency, promise, bluebird

I have two variables:

```
const primaryId = '123'; // always exactly one
const secondaryIds = ['234', '345', '456', '567', '678']; // can be many
```

I have to perform an async operation on each identifier, but I need to make sure that I am only ever performing at most 2 concurrent requests at a time. These are database operations and I want to avoid too much fan-out during one REST call.

The way I have it structured currently is as follows:

```
const primaryPromise = doPrimaryPromise(primaryId);
const secondaryPromise = Promise.map(
    secondaryIds,
    secondaryId => doSecondaryPromise(secondaryId),
    { concurrency: 1 }
);
return Promise.join(
    primaryPromise,
    secondaryPromise
);
```

However, the [Bluebird documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html) tells me that `Promise.join` will execute the promises concurrently. Will this approach still enforce the maximum concurrency from the `Promise.map`, or is it overridden by the top level `Promise.join`?

I am realizing as I am typing this that the `Promise` returned by the `Promise.map` is probably what's responsible for enforcing that concurrency limit, so I should be safe. But I would definitely appreciate some feedback on this approach.

**Note: `async/await` is not an option for me here, unfortunately.**

Comment: Forgot that there is some sort of "StackOverflow Code Review" site, maybe this is better suited for that.

Comment: How are async/await not options when you're already using promises?

Comment: The codebase is not quite hip on the node versions yet. Still on 6.